# Conectar api con base de datos en laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

Yo tengo dos apis en laravel y ya las tengo con token y todo, Pero me están pidiendo que configure las apis para que se conecte a otra base de datos que hay en otro servidor, También configure el controlador y no me está haciendo la conexión ya configure el .env, esa BD está en otro server, he buscado en internet y solo encuentro el que crea como otra base de datos en el mismo servidor.

Alguien tiene alguna idea de ¿Cómo realizar dicho proceso? soy algo nuevo en esto Gracias!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

debes agregar una nueva conexión en tu archivo

> config/database.php

y copiar una de las que ya están y la renombra. Por ejemplo si la conexión es en postgres y ya está usando la existente, copia todo el array de la configuración y la llama pgsql2 por ejemplo.

En el controlador cambias de conexion usando

```
$users = DB::connection('pgsql2')->select(...);
```